# akka dataflow and side effects

Tags: scala, akka, continuations, dataflow

I'm working with akka dataflow and I'd like to know if there is a way to cause a particular block of code to wait for the completion of a future, without explicitly using the value of that future.

The actual use case is that I have a file and I want the file to be deleted when a particular future completes, but not before.  Here is a rough example.  First imagine I have this service:

```
trait ASync {
   def pull: Future[File]
   def process(input : File): Future[File]
   def push(input : File): Future[URI]
}
```

And I have a workflow I want to run in a non-blocking way:

```
val uriFuture = flow {
    val pulledFile = async.pull(uri)
    val processedile = async.process(pulledFile())
    val storedUri = async.push(processedFile())

    // I'd like the following line executed only after storedUri is completed, 
    // not as soon as pulled file is ready.
    pulledFile().delete()

    storedUri()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
val uriFuture = flow {
  val pulledFile = async.pull(uri)
  val processedile = async.process(pulledFile())
  val storedUri = for(uri <- async.push(processedFile())) yield {
    pulledFile().delete()
    uri
  }
  storedUri()
}
```

In this example, `pulledFile.delete` will only be called if the `Future` from `push` succeeds.  If it fails, `delete` will not be called.  The result of the `storedUri` future will still be the result of the call to `push`.

Or another way would be:

```
val uriFuture = flow {
  val pulledFile = async.pull(uri)
  val processedile = async.process(pulledFile())
  val storedUri = async.push(processedFile()) andThen{
    case whatever => pulledFile().delete()
  }
  storedUri()
}
```

The difference here is that `delete` will be called regardless of if `push` succeeds or fails.  The result of `storedUri` still will be the result of the call to `push`.

Comment: The problem is that if I try to put pulledFile() inside any block that passed to a function on the Future returned from async.push, I get a ton of compile errors.  However, I found I do get it to compile if I assign pulledFile() to a val outside the block and then use it within the block.  I'll check if that runs correctly and then update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks for non-blocking workflow:

```
future onSuccess {
  case _ => file.delete() //Deal with cases obviously... 

}
```

Source: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html

Alternatively, you can block with Await.result:

```
val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
```

The latter is generally used when you NEED to block - eg in test cases - while non blocking is more performant as you don't park a thread to spin up another thread only to resume the other thread again - that's slower than an asynchronous activity because of the resource management overhead.

The typesafe staff are calling it "Reactive". That's a little bit of a buzzword. I would laugh if you used it in the workplace.